# Understanding xcode instruments for allocation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, instruments

[image]

My assumption is that the **red line** is the culprit for why my object is still retained. Is that the case? Where can I go to find out more information about this line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The red line is telling you that 90.4% of the memory allocated in the current method is allocated in the call to fadeOutSplash. Whether or not that line of code is causing your object to be retained can't be determined from the view in your screenshot.

If you look at the screenshot you can see an Info button next to the 90.4% listing. Clicking the button will show you the heaviest backtraces, the backtraces with the largest memory allocations. I'm not sure how much that information will help in your case, but it is additional information about that line of code.